# Ошибка 404 при проксировании nginx

Tags: nginx

Nginx, reverse-proxy. Два локейшена. Различаются только портом, протоколом и адресом. 
На адрес 192.168.40.41 запрос пролетает нормально.
На адрес 192.168.0.98 - нет.
Прилетает 404 ошибка, а nginx пытается найти этот путь у себя локально.
Как так?

Оба адреса с реверс-проски доступны по указанным протоколам и портам.

```
location /CheckMedInsCertService {
    proxy_pass            https://192.168.0.98:443/1CUSK_QUA/ws/CheckMedInsCertService;

    proxy_redirect        off;
    proxy_set_header      Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location /CheckMedInsCertService1 {
    proxy_pass            http://192.168.40.41/1CUSK_QUA/ws/CheckMedInsCertService;

    proxy_redirect        off;
    proxy_set_header      Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: А если изменить имя неработающего локейшена на что-то совсем-совсем другое, типа abcd? Я бы предположил, что он ошибается с соответствием локейшена (буква где-то неправильная, может быть?), поэтому предлагаю для проверки от текущего имени локейшена избавиться совсем, полностью (то есть не сокращать его до CheckMed, например). Ну и убедиться (анализатором пакетов), что машинка не пытается открывать соединение на 443-й порт 192.168.0.98 (а если всё же пытается, то всё вышенаписанное неверно).

Comment: На 192.168.0.98 пакетов на 443 порт не улетает. Таких пар локейшенов на самом деле три. Ведут себя все одинаково.